# Jasper Server: passing argument to get report data for customer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have almost the problem described here: [iReport: Passing parameters from a main report query to a dataset query for a table or list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681704/ireport-passing-parameters-from-a-main-report-query-to-a-dataset-query-for-a-ta)

but since it's a few years old, I'm using iReports 5.1 with the newest comnunity version of Jasper Server.

I am able to fetch reports by PHP from the server, but I want to pass a parameter to the report to only display information for a distinct customer, having something like customerId in the database. So it only generates a report for a give customerId.

I don't want to create a single report for every customer.

How can I pass arguments to the datasource/main report, through the API?

Additional question: Is it possible to add this argument/parameter to scheduled reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the report (XML):

```
<parameter name="CUSTOMERID" isForPrompting="false" class="java.lang.String">
</parameter>
```

In the datasource (mongodb):

```
{'collectionName':'test', findQuery : { customerId: $P{CUSTOMERID} }}
```

passing the argument:

```
 ws_runReport($currentUri, $report_params,  $output_params, $attachments);
```

*Hope this will help someone else, too.*