# Jasper : How to keep HTTP header in datasource from Jaspersoft Studio to server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

Consider the following :

I have a PHP web application. This application is protected from any intrusion via a middleware that looks for the correct credentials everytime a call to a route is done. If your are logged in correctly, the page is displayed. If not, you are kicked out. Simple and easy.

Now, this application provides me with links that return JSON. This JSON is generated for the sole purpose of reporting. In Jaspersoft Studio, I created a JSON data adapter and used the provided links as the URL.

[image]

But that was not it yet. Since a middleware is checking every link calls in the application, I needed to add an exception for my reports. I decided that passing an encrypted token in the HTTP header was the solution. I then added the option into our data adapter.

[image]

It worked like a charm!

Now, to the problem :

Using the information provided on the [Jaspersoft website](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-report-uses-remote-json-data-source), I exported my Data Adapter to the server. The thing is, the HTTP Header is not considered anymore when calling the data source from the server. Of course, my report does not work anymore. I then tested with a link hosted on another platform and it worked, even without the HTTP header.

So, my question is **how do I keep the HTTP header in my datasource from Jaspersoft Studio to the server?**

**Edit 1:** Jaspersoft Studio Version : 6.4.0, JasperSoft Server Version: 6.3.0

Comment: What versions of Studio and Server are you using?

Comment: @Narcis Jaspersoft Studio : 6.4.0, JasperSoft Server : 6.3.0 Build : 20160629_1853

Comment: I had a [similiar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317736/jasper-server-passing-argument-to-get-report-data-for-customer) and just passed a customer-id to the report as a parameter. I don't understand, why you use JSON from the application to generate reports, when you can directly generate reports from within the application (using the Jasper API). Why do you have this extra step?

Comment: @KeineMaster Those HTTP options were added in JasperReports 6.3.1. The closest Server version to support those features should be 6.4.0.

Comment: @DanFromGermany The JSON is generated by the application over several events. It was first designed to send JSON to a Webservice, but the option of doing reports was chosen after some times. Jasper seemed the best option since they can use JSON as Datasource.

Comment: @Narcis I will be updating the server later! I'm gonna check back with you! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Narcis after updating to 7.1, the issue was resolved! If you could post your useful comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it as the correct one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those HTTP options were added in JasperReports 6.3.1. The closest Server version to support those features should be 6.4.0.