# Can you call an ireport from php with two or more parameters?

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I am generating a report with php and ireport that works, but I can only send one parameter. I would like to send more then one parameter to create a better query in MySQL.

Here is my code to send just one parameter to the ireport with php:

My javascript function

```
  window.open("../Report1.php?Folio=" + folio);
```

```
<?php
$Folio=$_GET["Folio"];
   function DescargarArchivo($fichero)
    {
        $basefichero = basename($fichero);
        header( "Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header( "Content-Length: ".filesize($fichero));
        header( "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=" .$basefichero."");
        readfile($fichero);
    }

    $fecha = time ();
    $fecha_partir1=date ( "h" , $fecha ) ;
    $fecha_partir2=date ( "i" , $fecha ) ;
    $fecha_partir4=date ( "s" , $fecha ) ;
    $fecha_partir3=$fecha_partir1-1;
    $reporte="CC_";
    $filename = $reporte.''. $Folio.'.pdf';

    require_once('http://localhost:9977/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc');
    require('php-jru/php-jru.php');

    $jru=new PJRU();
     $Reporte='/var/www/html/ireportFile.jasper';
    //save file
    $SalidaReporte='/var/www/html/'.$filename;

    //here I declare paramenres
    $Parametro=new java('java.util.HashMap');
    $Parametro->put("Folio", $Folio);

    //mysql
    $Conexion= new  JdbcConnection("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://localhost/Ignisterra?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","local","local");

    $jru->runReportToPdfFile($Reporte,$SalidaReporte,$Parametro,$Conexion->getConnection());
    if(file_exists($SalidaReporte)) 
    {   
        DescargarArchivo($filename);
        if(file_exists($SalidaReporte)) 
        { 
            if(unlink($filename)) 
            {       
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the query in ireport using the parameter `$P{Folio}` I sent in:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_1 WHERE ID = $P{Folio};
```

With this code, I can only submit one parameter. I don't know how to modify this to send more then one parameter to an ireport.

I hope this explanation is clear enough. Regards

Comment: Syntactically more correct, with more common English phrasing to clarify the user's meaning.

Comment: I need to send two parameter to my `ireportFile.jasper` with this code I can only send one

Comment: You may be able to get assistance on how to pass multiple parameters from the answer below and this [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681704/ireport-passing-parameters-from-a-main-report-query-to-a-dataset-query-for-a-ta) that, while similar, discusses passing multiple parameters from a master report to a sub report. Review them both to see if you can make the process work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&` to do something like this...

`window.open("../Report1.php?Folio=" + folio + "&OtherVariable=" + otherVariable);`

then in your PHP file, say something like...

`$otherVar = $_GET["OtherVariable"]`

Also, using post would be more secure and you add can multiple parameters (additional variables) to your post call without insecurely making them visible in the request URL.

Comment: what would work in a php report but I using Ireport